# How to run Magento 2 with pub as document root?

Tags: magento2

I have a nexcess hosting with document root `/home/aae3re95/dev.example.com/html` and i need to set `/home/aae3re95/dev.example.com/html/pub` as document web root.

Please tell me steps to make pub as document root.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check if you are using apache/ngnix ecc.

If you are using nginx go in /etc/ngnix/site-avaible and search for $MAGE_ROOT variable.

If you don't know about this kind of things try this command:

```
grep -nri '/home/aae3re95/dev.example.com/html' /
```

It will show you where it's placed the variable to change.

Cheers